# How get url of current page with javascript in google sites?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the url of the current page with javascript in Google Sites?
I need to get the full url of current page with all parameters.
`window.location.href` return `http://nosuchhost.invalid:80`.
It happens in Google Sites only, in Google blogs `window.location.href` works fine.

Comment: what do you mean, "in google sites"? `window.location.href` is working fine for me in GMail, for instance.

Comment: I think he's talkin about: http://sites.google.com

Comment: I suspect maybe since google is so obsessed with the data URI, maybe they have an iframe into which they shove your content. o.0 -- have you tried `window.top.location.href`?

Comment: yes i mean  sites.google.com. window.top.location.href return a same http://nosuchhost.invalid:80.

Comment: Now that there's an answer that is correct, you should accept the answer to show the question as resolved!

Answer (score 3):

[You can't run javascript in a google site](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/0tIPJ_qFaW0).

> It won't work as I don't think Google Sites will ever offer JavaScript.
>
> What you have to remember is that your Google Site is always at a
>   google.com address and, therefore, many people, firewalls and virus
>   checkers automatically trust everything at a google.com address:
>   Javacript can deliver malicious code, so it's never going to happen.
>   You should be able to add the javascript through a gadget.

and...

> As Steegle has noted, we won't be adding JavaScript anytime soon to
>   the capabilities of Sites.

Comment: Now it's possible to add CSS, Javascript ang HTML to google sites using HTML Box, but I don't recommand :) The loading of the resources it's very slow. It's better if you write a gadget in gadget editor and simply include them in your site :)